# Sending commands to CANalyzer CAPL application via socket

Tags: sockets, can-bus, capl

I need to control a complex CAN simulator written in CAPL for CANalyzer from an external application (in java, if that matters).

The simulator is already written and it has some buttons performing the functions I need.

What I need now is to modify this simulator so it accepts commands from a custom application, presumably via socket connection (but I'm open to other IPC means).

I should be able to send a message to Simulator and it should act as-if one of the interface buttons had been pushed.

Can such a thing be (easily) done? If so: where can I find relevant documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out CANalyzer does not (currently) have socket interface (CANoe does).

Preferred interfacing method is via COM server (both CANalyzer and CANoe act as CAN server by default). See: https://www.vector.com/portal/medien/vector_cantech/faq/ProgrammingWithCAPL.pdf

Answer (score 1):

If you are using COM server, you will be able to make your application interact and exchange messages with CANalyzer. There is an application note document (pdf) at http://vector.com/portal/medien/cmc/application_notes/AN-AND-1-117_CANoe_CANalyzer_as_a_COM_Server.pdf describing the details. And you will find a sample configuration in the installation path of your CANalyzer under \CANwin Demos\Demo_CAN_CN\MoreExamples\COM_Automation for visual basic script.

Comment: StackOverflow prefers that a summary of the details is included in the answer rather than giving a URL link to a document that may eventually become a dead link. Can you summarise?

Comment: I see your point for avoiding dead links, but for this special question, it is necessary that the user goes through all 18 pages of the linked document in detail to understand what he needs to do. There is no useful way to summarize these 18 pages (at least I have no idea how I could come up to this).

Comment: Yup, link is dead, just like Brian said.

Comment: The link redirects to https://assets.vector.com/cms/content/know-how/_application-notes/AN-AND-1-117_CANoe_CANalyzer_as_a_COM_Server.pdf since last year.